# Run cucumber features from command line with for different test environments

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am new to Cucumber and Ruby. I have a cucumber feature and running this from command line. I have given my QA test environment connection details in my step definition .rb file. When i run it in QA i have no issue at it always points to QA. But if i want to run in Dev or PT, i have to go and change connection URLs in .rb step definition file. Is there any option to run the feature file just by specifying the test region in command line like below...

C:> Cucumber features [Dev or QA or IT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the following code in `features/support/env.rb`:

```
case ENV['MY_ENV']
when 'Dev' then # initialize Dev
when 'QA' then # initialize QA
else ...
end
```

and run it like:

```
MY_ENV=Dev cucumber
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I have did the same what you suggested and its working fine and i have one more question. How to exit or terminate the cucumber feature execution during the execution time. For example, in env.rb file i have my 'case' to select the environments from command line. If the ENV[''] is not having the proper region from command line, then in else statement i puts "region is not found" and i want to terminate the execution flow. I tried with exit(0), return, raise() ... But not working..Could you please help me how to terminate the execution in runtime?

Comment: I tried like this exit(). But i get this output in command promt. Is this right?. No region is specified to run

invalid option: -t

minitest options:
    -h, --help                       Display this help.
    -s, --seed SEED                  Sets random seed. Also via env. Eg: SEED=n rake
    -v, --verbose                    Verbose. Show progress processing files.
    -n, --name PATTERN               Filter run on /pattern/ or string.

Known extensions: pride
    -p, --pride                      Pride. Show your testing pride!

Comment: It looks like an output of `whatever --help`, and, probably, depends on other environment/bundle settings.

Comment: Thanks much @mudasobwa. My command line execution is working fine. But facing another issue. All features are running fine when started with command line with TEST_ENV=Dev given. But when i open the rubymine and run the individual features, it asks me the input for TEST_ENV. So i am not sure on this.Is there any option to check whether the feature is initiated thro' command line or not. so that i can navigate accordingly.?

Comment: I have no clue about Redmine, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I use hashie+yml to manage my config files which require not only the ability to give me different urls based on the environment I hit but also based in the application I intend to run the test on... Below is an example:

First you want a yaml file where you can add your config infos, you can call it "config.yml" for example:

```
---
test:
  url: http://test.com
dev: 
  url: http://dev.com
```

Then a module that will be responsible to expose your yaml file, you can call it "config.rb" for example:

```
module Config
  #this line creates a constant with the environment variable value
  ENV_CONFIG = ENV['ENV_CONFIG'] || 'test'

  #this method loads your yaml with hashie
  def load_file(file_name)
    Hashie::Mash.load(Dir.pwd + '/lib/config/' + file_name + '.yml')
  end

  #this is the method that you will use to read your yaml based on 
  #your ENV_CONFIG value
  def env_config
    config ||= load_file('config').send("#{ENV_CONFIG}")
  end
end
```

Then in your env.rb require config.rb file, then include "Config" module... once you do that you are set to use the info present in your yaml based on ENV_CONFIG environment variable that you set in your command line...

You can run access the yaml info the following way:

```
env_config.url
> "http://test.com" #if your ENV_CONFIG is "test"
```

When you trigger cucumber, run it by attributing the environment variable (if you dont the code will default to test)

```
cucumber ENV_CONFIG='dev'
```